# The number of divisors being less than or equal to twice the square root of a natural number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Ok I have been working through my new book that arrived in the mail this week, "Problems in Analytic Number Theory" Second Edition, by M.Ram Murty.

Exercise 1.3.1 asks the reader to show that:

$$d(n) \leq 2 \sqrt{n}$$

and the solution simply states that because every divisor $\alpha$ of $n$ corresponds to a factorization $\alpha \beta=n$, and of course one of $\alpha$ or $\beta$ must be less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$, the **number** of divisors must be less than or equal to $2 \sqrt{n}$.

In as much as yes I can see this to be the most simple and straight forward proof one can arrive at for this problem, there is still something that makes me feel uneasy, almost as if there is a intermediate lemma that is too obvious to the author to warrant inclusion, unfortunately, not so much is as obvious to me, so I was hoping someone could see what this is.

I just don't see how we get from knowing the elementary fact that one of the two factors of a particular factorization  (ie, the product of a particular divisor and the rest ) being required to be less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$,allows for us to make a similar conclusion concerning the total **number** of such factorizations.

Comment: Try to see what happens if a number greater than √n is taken as a factor of n. Does it work?

Comment: Ok thanks Martin I will take  a look.

Comment: It's unique factorization (the fundamental theorem of algebra) that you might be missing.

Comment: true you might be right there Michael I don't know I think I might be being a sore loser here because it looked easy and I was forced to look at the back of the book and *still* had some form of confusion, unfortunately with me if I don't hash out these little things they rear their head in embarrassing ways later on

Comment: The point is to pair divisors whose product yields $n$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For every divisor $d$, make the ordered pair $(d,\frac nd)$.  The number of such ordered pairs is $d(n)$, clearly.  Split them into three types, those with $d<\frac nd, d=\frac nd,d>\frac nd$.  The middle group contains at most $1$ element, namely, $(\sqrt n,\sqrt n)$.  The other two groups are in bijection with each other, by reversing the terms.  Letting $A(n)$ be the number of elements in group $1$ we then see that:

$$d(n) =
\begin{cases}
2A(n),  & \text{if $n$ is not a perfect square} \\
2A(n)+1 , & \text{if $n$ is a perfect square}
\end{cases}$$

How big is $A(n)$?

Well, the smaller member of any ordered pair other than $(\sqrt n,\sqrt n)$ must be less than $\sqrt n$, clearly (otherwise both members would be $>\sqrt n$ hence the product would be greater than $n$). Thus $A(n)<\sqrt n$.  It follows that

$$d(n) <
\begin{cases}
2\sqrt n,  & \text{if $n$ is not a perfect square} \\
2\sqrt n+1 , & \text{if $n$ is a perfect square}
\end{cases}$$

This is very close to what you wanted, but not exact.  Of course, we can tighten our estimates.    We distinguish two cases:

If $n$ is not a perfect square.  In that case we already have $d(n)<2\sqrt n$ so we are done.

If $n$ is a perfect square then the fact that $2\sqrt n+1$ and $d(n)$ are both integers tells us that $$d(n)<2\sqrt n+1\implies d(n)≤2\sqrt n$$

Comment: ok thankyou very much for this @lulu this is perfect

Comment: sorry @lulu what is the correct term to use for the subsets formed by imposing the predicates for the 3 inequalities as you described?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  I don't know that there is a standard term for the subsets I described...as far as I know, they are specific to this question.

Comment: Still the point eludes me that in $A(n)$ being the cardinality for group 1, I am still finding it hard to come to terms with the concept that because the minimum of any given ordered pair that is an element of group 1 must be less than the square root of n, this must also be the case for $A(n)$, I just can't see how we make the connective between size of the smaller member of any given element, and the cardinality of the set of ordered pairs itself, I understand I must be frustrating but it's just the way it is, what is *not* intuitive for me is often embarrassingly so for all others

Comment: Let $A(n)$ stand for both the set I mentioned and its order.  An element in that set is entirely determined by it's least element.  What could the least element be?  Well, the least it could be is $1$.  The greatest it could be can not exceed $\sqrt n$, by definition.  Thus $A(n)≤\sqrt n$.  To be sure, excluding very small $n$, it is hard to imagine $A(n)$ being anywhere near as big as $\sqrt n$, but at least that is an upper bound.  Since $A(n)$ is an integer you can immediately improve this to $A(n)≤\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor$ if that helps.

Comment: General note:  you are perfectly right to vex at details.  I've seen large scale results in analytic number theory get shut down because of some technical blunder at the early stage.

Comment: OK yes I'm starting to see how easy this should be now, but yes you understand where I am coming from, I've gone ahead of myself and made a whole lot of conjectures based on observation for related things in a more complex context, and the proofs and or progress for them are eluding me mainly because I've never actually picked up a graduate level textbook and worked my way through all of the things that everyone else has

Comment: Just to say:  in this case, I'd say the danger would be for small $n$.  For large $n$ , there are going to be quite a few integers $<\sqrt n$ which do not divide $n$.  For $n=4$ though, every natural number $<\sqrt n$ divides it (not so hard, as $1$ is the only such integer).  Even then, however, $d(n)=3<2\sqrt 4$.

Comment: sure the first step I took in my first attempt was actually just to take the floor of the square root to improve the bound based on the knowledge of the number of divisors being a natural number, there was a question I asked last week regarding an inequality involving $d(n)$, if I am able to transfer this kind of frame work to that I'll consider it a win

Comment: ah here it is. You will see what I mean about me having raced ahead without some elementary considerations that would probably clarify this one a lot for me, perhaps you can help me here also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2890356/congruence-relation-proof-over-two-integer-variables

Comment: When I have finished the latex for the example relevant to the other question it maybe more clear what I am carrying on about, but the general idea you came up with to separate ordered pairs generated from a particular arithmetic function into three subsets as you did here I think is potentially on the most powerful tools involving elementary Set Theory that I've found applicable to Number Theory, the number of possible elements in the middle group, and ascertaining whether or not there is a bijection between the two groups either side, very helpful stuff

Comment: sorry final comment I will be labelling the lemma I intend to construct a proof( for the linked question )based on the general method you used here as I previously referred to

Answer (score 2):

You've already observed that there is a pairing between divisors greater than $\sqrt{n}$ and those less than $\sqrt{n}$.  To get that this pairing, you need the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, i.e., there's no way to use the same factor twice.

Since every pair has a distinct factor less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$ and there are $\sqrt{n}$ positive numbers less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$, this gives the desired count.

Comment: I know I am just deflecting blame here, but I really feel as if the fundamental theorem of algebra and arithmetic should have been drilled into me throughout secondary school, I mean it's not a more difficult a concept than the trigonometry they did teach us, anyway just a thought, perhaps no amount of education could ever help me\

Answer (score 1):

List all the divisors of $n$:

$$d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_k.$$

Note that $k = \tau(n)$.  These divisors come in pairs. For each $d_i$ that divides $n$, there is a $d_j$ such that $d_id_j = n.$  By your little fact, one of these hast to be less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}.$  That means half of the divisors are less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$.  There are only $\sqrt{n}$ possible values for $d_i$, then.  And hence only $\sqrt{n}$ possible values for $d_j$. In total that's at most $2\sqrt{n}$ divisors.

When you see it, you'll go "Doh!"

Comment: I know but i promised myself I would post whenever I was confused over something straight forward to everyone else, it's sort of a means of making sure it has a "memorable" learning process to put it nicely